# Regex : How do I replace a number with zero?

Tags: regex, linux, vim, vi

I have lines as below in a file

> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=220124
>
> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=232
>
> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22

I am trying to get output as below

> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0
>
> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0
>
> ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0

I used

> %s/AUTO_INCREMENT=*/AUTO_INCREMENT=0/g

but did not work.

Comment: What have you tried. Did you search the net?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: cross-site dupe: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10385/5298

Comment: `*` isn't a wild card.  `.` means match any single character. `.*` means match any character 0 or more times.  `.+` means match any character 1 or more times.

Comment: `%s/AUTO_INCREMENT=.*/AUTO_INCREMENT=0/g` would work

Comment: You can also avoid typing AUTO_INCREMENT the second time by specifying where you want the replacement to start by using `\zs`

Comment: `:%s/AUTO_INCREMENT=\zs.*/0/g`

Answer (score 2):

**Replaces numbers with 0**

```
:%s/\d\+/0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
%s/=\s*\d\+\s*$/=0/
```

- it only changes `...=numbers`, won't change the number in the middle of lines. E.g. in your variable name, if there was
- it changes `=     123` to `=0`
- it changes `=123(spaces....)` to `=0`
- it **won't** change `=foo123`

Answer (score 0):

Depends what language you want to use, so I can't really help you with the code. However, the regex is quite simple, you could do a search for:

`ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=(\d+)`

And replace it with:

`ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a capturing group:

```
%s/\(.*=\).*/\10
```

This works because Vim's regex engine is greedy. Instead of stopping the match in the first equal sign, it keeps capturing until it finds the last equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```
%s/AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]*/AUTO_INCREMENT=0/g
```